# Eclipse Project description - NOT .project file - is there such a thing?

Tags: eclipse, documentation, project

I have a whole bunch of Eclipse projects, large and small, that I want to keep organized.  I'm trying to figure out if there is some sort of property that can be attached to the project in order to provide a description of what the project is or what it was created to do or test.  I would hope that this field can be easily viewed at the time you are browsing through a list of projects.  It would be nice if I could put descriptive text into this field and not have to consider giving my projects names like 'TwitterOAuth2TestImplementationUsingScribe'

Anything that would allow you to browse your projects in a way similar to this (each line represents an Eclipse project):

```
 Myproj1             Simple Test Project
 LogTest3            Test new logging class
 NetworkUDPTests     Testing UDP classes
 OAuth2Example       Sample project for Oauth2
```

Unfortunately, project "description" is the name of the .project file that stores each project's settings, so it is a bit harder to search for information on this.

Comment: I usually add a readme.txt to the root of every project, makes it easier and isn't eclipse dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an interesting question we also face. Currently there does not seem to exist a solution for this problem. The only thing that could come near to providing one is the [Mylyn Intent](http://www.eclipse.org/intent/) project, as it aims to provide a comprehensive documentation on design decisions, which takes into account the inter-dependencies between plugins.

This inter-dependency is exactly the problem. There exist solutions to document the purpose of [java packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment) which is limited to the classes however.

Our solution is a readme.textile embedded in the root of each plugin, providing this specific information. It would, however, be interesting to introduce the documentation used for packages for bundle documentation, which could be used to autogenerate an overview documentation.

Comment: Best answer contributed so I've accepted it, thanks for your suggestions and input

Answer (score 0):

There is a **comment** tag in the `.project` file: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/project_description_file.html

However it looks like Eclipse itself doesn't use the content of this tag. I changed it manually but after that I've never seen the text I entered anywhere in Eclipse